# react-table row selection with custom field instead of index

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm using the [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect#userowselect) package. I made a simple table with row selection. The problem is: The row selection result is an object with indexes:

```
{
 0: true,
 1: true,
 ...
}
```

But I want to be the primary key of my data like this:

```
{
  EXoxMjyd4leYABdpuy8m: true,
  2gXlClA38AU8sSM5jnZ7: true,
  ...
}
```

[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/row-selection)

In the documentation, I can't find a configuration where I can set the selection key.
The question is, how can I achieve the second example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to overwrite the [table option](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#table-options) `getRowId`.

Example:

```
const getRowId = (row, relativeIndex, parent) => {
   // In row object you have access to data. 
   // You can choose parameter. In this example I used uniqueId
   return parent ? [parent.id, row.uniqueId].join('.') : row.uniqueId;
}
```

Here is live example:

[image: Edit tannerlinsley/react-table: row-selection-controlled (forked)]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **version 8** react-table; you can use `instance.getSelectedRowModel()` in order to get the original (data model of the rows) of the selected rows as well as the row indexes.

For instance:

```
const arraySelectedUsersId = instance.getSelectedRowModel().rows.map(({ original }) => (original as User).id)
```